# What is the right way to post a message to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Lots of Q's about this but none of the answers seem to work.

I want to post a message from my main window, to an iframe.  But nothing I do seems to work, no errors, the message just never arrives. As shown here (has to be Fiddle as SO snippet didn't seem to work):

https://jsfiddle.net/z7w2tm0j/17/

I create an iframe:

```
   const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.innerHTML = 'Message goes here';
   iframe.setAttribute('id', 'sandboxIframe'); 
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

attach a script component that adds a message listener:

```
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument //Can also add directly to iframe, same result


const script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.innerHTML = `

        window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

          console.log("got message:");
          console.log(event);
        });
        window.postMessage('test', '*');//this message arrives
    `;

 iframeDocument.body.appendChild(script)
```

Then call postMessage from animation frame,

```
 const update = ()=>{
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('foo','*'); //this message never arrives (if targetOrigin is not '*' this throws an exception)
    console.log("Sent message");
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update);

 }
 update();
```

What the magic thing I'm missing for this to work?

Comment: Is the bottom snippet in the parent or in the iframe?

Comment: Um, it appears to be running fine in your fiddle. On latest chrome.

Comment: Dammit!  I have no idea why that started work :(

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that fiddle has started working.  I wasn't paying attention:)

changing

```
 iframe.appendChild(script)
```

to

```
 iframeDocument.body.appendChild(script)
```

Fixed it.

Thanks all